# Is there a way to remove deps config in requirejs-config.js in the other module?

Tags: magento2.3, requirejs, requirejs-config.js

I'm following the steps in [this article](https://medium.com/@jahvi/how-to-improve-magento-2-page-speed-insights-score-bb37e8946192) on a default Magento sample data version and I want to remove **'mage/translate-inline'** ADM from injected into the page. See here - https://prnt.sc/t7ao6j

Is there a way to remove deps config in requirejs-config.js in the other module from my module?

Comment: check if https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/javascript-dev-guide/javascript/custom_js.html works for u

Comment: I reviewed it, but there isn't a way to solve the issue that I'm having.

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to do it.
In `[Namespace]/[Module]/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js` add this:

```
// The config variable used to requirejs accepts this file
var config = {};

(function(require){
    var depsNodeRef = require.s.contexts._.config.deps;

    var index = depsNodeRef.indexOf('path/to/file');
    if (index > -1) {
        depsNodeRef.splice(index, 1);
    }
})(require);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a patch for modify the requirejs-config.js file in vendor/magento/module-translation ?